# Why is my parameter null when I try to pass object using MS AJAX PageMethods

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I tried the following snippet as well:

```
PageMethods.MyMethod(JSON.stringify(person), OnMyMethodComplete);
```

**Client markup:**

```
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var person = { firsName: "World" };
        function test() {
            PageMethods.MyMethod(person, OnMyMethodComplete);
        }

        function OnMyMethodComplete(result) { alert(result); }

        window.onload = function () {
            test();
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MyMethod(Person p)
{
    return "Hello " + p.FirstName;
}
```

**Debug:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried pass "person" as parameter to function test()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was defining `var Person` in client code, but looking for `var p` on the server-side.